# Paypal Express Checkout Error in CodeIgniter, Gocart(Method Specified is not Supported)

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal-sandbox

I am new to codeigniter and paypal. I am working on gocart(an open source eCommerce solution built on codeIgniter). I try to work on paypal API integrated in it, but its showing error as follows : `[ACK] => Failure    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 81002    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Unspecified Method    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Method Specified is not Supported    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error` 
  Below is my code :
**paypal_expres.php**

```
 function __construct() 
{

$this->API_USERNAME ='Username';

$this->API_PASSWORD = 'Password';

$this->API_SIGNATURE ='Signature';

$this->RETURN_URL = 'www.example.com';

$this->CANCEL_URL = 'www.example.com';

$this->currency = 'USD';
$this->host = "api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com";

$this->gate = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
}
```

public function doExpressCheckout($amount, $desc, $invoice='')
{
    $data = array(
    'PAYMENTACTION' =>'Sale',    'AMT' => '24',    'RETURNURL' => $this->getReturnTo(),
    'CANCELURL'  => $this->getReturnToCancel(),    'CURRENCYCODE'=> $this->currency,    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout');

$query = $this->buildQuery($data);
$result = $this->response($query);
$response = $result->getContent();
$return = $this->responseParse($response);
echo '';
print_r($return);
echo '';
if ($return['ACK'] == 'Success') 
{
header('Location: '.$this->gate.'cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token='.$return['TOKEN'].'');
die();    }

return($return);}

public function doExpressCheckout($amount, $desc, $invoice='')
{
$data = array(    'PAYMENTACTION' =>'Sale',    'AMT' => '24',    'RETURNURL' => $this->getReturnTo(),    'CANCELURL'  => $this->getReturnToCancel(),    'CURRENCYCODE'=> $this->currency,    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout');

$query = $this->buildQuery($data);
$result = $this->response($query);
$response = $result->getContent();
$return = $this->responseParse($response);
echo '';
print_r($return);
echo '';

if ($return['ACK'] == 'Success') 
{
header('Location: '.$this->gate.'cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token='.$return['TOKEN'].'');
die();    }

return($return);
}

private function response($data)
{
$result = $this->CI->httprequest->connect($data);
if ($result<400) 
return 
$this->CI->httprequest;
return false;}

private function buildQuery($data = array())
{
$data['USER'] = $this->API_USERNAME;
$data['PWD'] = $this->API_PASSWORD;
$data['SIGNATURE'] = $this->API_SIGNATURE;
$data['VERSION'] = '56.0';
$query = http_build_query($data);
return $query;
}

Comment: Can you provide some code to explain it a little bit more..?

Comment: GoCart has support forum > http://gocartdv.com/community .
Better ask there for your problem!

Comment: @Hiren I have posted my code. Thanks Svetlio let me also ask from them.